# How to edit the top level default.aspx in WSS3 site with VS(2010)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wss-3.0

I can open the default.aspx of a sub-site no problem.( file open,type or browse to the url )

BUT I can't open the default.aspx of the top-level site or a WSS site, in VS2010.

I have to use SPD.

Is there a permission to set somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit sharepoint sites in VS 2010. Indirect way would be to download default.aspx, edit in VS 2010 and upload it back. However its cumbersome and not recommended.

SharePoint Designer is the preferred way to edit Sharepoint sitse.

Comment: This may be another question: When I use SPD, it keeps adding __Error.. to my User Controls and breaking the page...any idea how to make that stop?

Comment: Yep I'll use a combination of SPD and VS, solved the other problem myself though...